# Unable to dual boot windows 7,8, and ubuntu using w8 bootloader

Tags: dual-boot

I had a sony vaio running windows 7 and Ubuntu but I had given it to my friend as he needed it,
I bought  a new desktop with windows 7 and windows 8 dual booted using w8 boot loader,
Now I am trying to boot Ubuntu but I want to boot it from windows 8 boot loader can anyone please help so I can boot all 3 oses from same boot screen.Please help,
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you want to use the Windows bootloader? GRUB is installed by default when you install Ubuntu and it does the same thing.

Comment: I want to use windows 8 boot loader because of its graphical interface,it looks good